# How to avoid trailing spaces in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

I store data in T-SQL server and use `nchar` fields to store string values.

The problem is that after selecting element from database I have very long string ended with spaces.

Can I set another field in database to avoid such situation, or have I do it in my ORM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite the DB to store string values as [`nvarchar`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) if it better represents your data.

If rewriting your DB is not possible or practical, then you have to trim the trailing spaces in your ORM.

Comment: The trim for all cases will give you some errors as somewhere you will have a field that needs the training spaces. In database design it is very important too use the correct type for your fields, working round erros costs a lot

Comment: @Mark Absolutely true Mark. It is exponentially costly to compensate for improper DB design in 'higher layers'; much better to re-design even if it seems daunting (in this case, changing a field's data type from `nchar` to `nvarchar` is everything but daunting).

Comment: Yes, I've made mistake while implementing tables... I've changed `nchar` to `varchar` and I've updated every string-like field with `REPLACE`. I see that select query returns truncatenated strings, but in application I still have trailing spaces. I think it's because ORM has to be recompiled to work with new type of database field, but unfortunatelly I don't have access to server. @prokilomer I will check it tomorrow and probably accept your answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the other answer.  You can also deal with it in the select

[RTRIM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178660.aspx)

A situation to use char or nchar is to prevent fragmentation.
If value starts null but you are going to later add a value then space is reserved.